# X axis doesn't lift after levelling

Tags: marlin, creality-ender-3, z-probe, inductive-sensor, skr-v1.4

So, I recently installed an inductive sensor to my 3D printer for auto bed levelling and now I'm stuck on Z probe offset as it doesn't seem to do much apart from changing number is given on display for the Z-axis. On tutorials that I watched, after Z homing, the print head lifted and allowed to set Z offset but my 3D printer doesn't do the same thing as in the tutorial. I'm not sure if its a problem in Marlin or a physical issue with my 3D printer. If anyone can help me I will be thankful as I'm stuck on this issue for a few days now. Also how far above the nozzle should the sensor be for it to work and not wipe off the 3D prints.

My 3D printer is a Creality Ender 3, glass bed, SKR 1.4 with Marlin 2.0.x firmware and an inductive sensor (LJ18A3-8-Z/BX-5V).

Comment: If it is after leveling/probing, it will never wipe prints off, it will pose a problem with priming though. Note this isn't a Z probe offset problem, instead, this is a Z position problem. Please look into [this answer](/a/12173), which describes the Z offset. Note that setting the correct value for this offset is essential for your prints to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered something which could be the answer to the problem, in Marlin compiling there is:
`//#define Z_AFTER_PROBING           2 // Z position after probing is done`

You have to uncomment it and change number 2 to how many millimeters you want it to be above the 3D printer bed.